# download from testflight or run as release version, My app can't load image correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I use [UIImage imageNamed:] load image from Assets.xcassets , The extension of image file is png.  And I run and install by Xcode with debug scheme, It's everything work fine.  But run and install by Xcode with release scheme, It can't load image file, the [UIImage imageNamed:] return nil.  And I upload to testfight and download from testflight ,the image is return nil too.

And, My iPad mini work fine, Run and test by iPad Air ,it's wrong.

If any guys know this problem? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the @2x and @3x images? Then try to do cmd+shift+k to clean your project and rebuild.

Also make sure that in your Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, Assests.xcassets are included.

Comment: Yes, I did it.  And right now I deal with this question by this way , In our xcode -> Build Settings -> Optimization level , change the level of release version to None. That's ok now.  And I know this isn't a accurate solution.